# How to divide a certain country on a map into grids?

Tags: openlayers-2, coordinates, vector-grid

I want to divide a certain country into grids 1,2,3,..., which are divided equally - in other words, have the same width and length. Then, I want to know into which grid a point coordinate will fall and put a mark into that grid. The grids lines will not be visible. For example, if I have points a,b,c, I need to put these points into the grids according to their coordinates. Accuracy is not an issue. I prefer a way that does not require any paid or rate limited services if possible. My application programming languages are Python and JavaScript. I'm using OpenLayers to draw markers on the map.

I'm totally new to GIS systems and maps. I need something to start with. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Using python you can manipulate Quantum GIS (QGIS) functions, but it is very simple for a GIS Desktop user,here is just an example to help you understand better:

1 - To create a GRID, Using QGIS, see figures below:

[image: Vector Grid]

[image: Vector Grid - Options]

2 - Now, enable this plugin:

[image: Spatial Query Plugin]

3 - Add your point Layer and Use this Tool:

[image: Adding a point layer]

4 - Make the spatial query

[image]

5 - Here is the result

[image]

I hope this will help a little bit

Comment: This is what I needed. I created a vector grid on country X and then I exported the grid layer as sqlite file to use it from within my project. Thank you sir.

Comment: @MarcelloBenigno Can you please help me here-  https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/246955/how-to-divide-x-y-plane-into-a-grid